# Unexpected result with very simple regexp

Tags: php, regex

I am fairly new to regexp and have encountered a regexp that delivers an unexpected result, when trying to match name parts in name of the form *firstname-fristname firstname*:

```
preg_match_all('/([^- ])*/i', 'aNNA-äöå Åsa', $result);
```

gives a `print_r($result)` that looks like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => aNNA
        [1] => 
        [2] => äöå
        [3] => 
        [4] => Åsa
        [5] => 
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => A
        [1] => 
        [2] => å
        [3] => 
        [4] => a
        [5] => 
    )
```

)

Now the `$result[0]` has the items I would want and expect as result, but where the heck do the `$results[1]` come from - I see it's the word endings, but how come they are matched?

And as a little side question, how do I prevent the empty matches (`$results[0][1]`, `$results[0][3]`, ...), or better even: Why do they show up - they are not not- or not-space either?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try with:

```
preg_match_all('/([^- ]+)/', 'aNNA-äöå Åsa', $result);
```

Your regex:

```
/([^- ])*/i
```

means: find one char that is not `^` or space and keep it in a group 0 or more times

This one:

```
/([^- ]+)/
```

means: find one or more char that is not `^` or space and keep it in a group

Moreover, there's no need for case insensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I feel real clever stumbling on the little difference of * and +, hehe :) I ended up using this `[^ -]+|[\-]+|[ ]+`regexp, as to also capture the - and spaces for recombining the name after capitalizing it.

Answer (score 1):

The * means "0 or more of the preceding."  Since a "-" is *exactly 0* of the the character class, it is matched.  However, since it is omitted from the character class, the capture fails to grab anything, leaving you an empty entry.  The expression giving you the expected behavior would be:

```
preg_match_all('/([^- ])+/i', 'aNNA-äöå Åsa', $result);
```

("+" means "1 or more of the preceding.")

Comment: Ty for the easy to understand walk-through of why I get empty matches. +1

Answer (score 1):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php says:

> Orders results so that $matches[0] is an array of full pattern
>   matches, $matches[1] is an array of strings matched by the first
>   parenthesized subpattern, and so on.

Check the URL for more details

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I assume I could try with different flags to achieve the desired result.